# Jenkins: GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling

Tags: jenkins

I try to configure Jenkins. I want a simple behavior: trigger a build on new pull request.

So, I created a job and configured it, but I checked the checkbox for:
[image]

And as you can see nothing is dropped down.

If I click the question mark on the right side, I see:

> If jenkins will receive PUSH GitHub hook from repo defined in Git SCM
>   section it will trigger Git SCM polling logic. So polling logic in
>   fact belongs to Git SCM.

But where is the "Git SCM section"?

Answer (score 17):

You need to configure the webhook on your GitHub repository. Then, on every commit push, Jenkins will be notified.

So, open your repository in the browser, then go to `Settings > Webhooks` and add a new one.

[image]

Then, enter the URL of your Jenkins instance followed by `/github-webhook` and select the other options depending on your needs:

[image]

Comment: Now in GitHub we have separate section WebHooks.

Comment: the "just the push event" will work for PR creation?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa I don't think so because there's a [PullRequestEvent](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/events/github-event-types#pullrequestevent), you should probably select "send me everything".

Answer (score 10):

I was also frustrated with this topic, this was needed for me to get job triggering working from GitHub MERGE:

- GitHub repo -> Settings -> Webhooks -> push type webhook with URL:
  `http(s)://host:<port>/github-webhook/`

  For me, last slash was **REQUIRED**, did not work without it
- In Jenkins System Settings, add GitHub Server, credential for it and [x] Manage hooks
- Use Test settings button to test it works
- In Job configuration, Source Code Management -> Git, add repo and credentials
- Under Build triggers: [x] GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling
- In GitHub webhook settings, click webhook and it shows logs how it worked under "Recent Deliveries" title

Answer (score 0):

It is a source code management section (before triggering section),
uncheck "none" case and check git ou github case(depend to your version) and fill the input field with your git repo url and credential[image]

Comment: This section does not exist in my UI

Answer (score 0):

All of the above are valid. But this one just to verify that the slash "/" at the end of the webhook you put on github is very important!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).