# Service hook in azure devops not triggering a build in jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

I am trying to use azure devops service hook for Jenkins build. While testing from azure devops to jenkins test connection is successful but GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling is not triggering the build if I am committing a code change in azure devops repo.

Comment: Did you come with any solution, Same is the case the test connection in azure console shows fine but not triggering the jenkins jobs

Answer (score 0):

If you just want GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling, you can check in [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093039/jenkins-github-hook-trigger-for-gitscm-polling) for help.

If you have trouble triggering a build in jenkins job when change code in Azure DevOps, here are two possibilities.
On the one hand, the url that you set was not right format. Please check your URL for your Git repository in Azure DevOps Services. The URL is in the form :
`https://dev.azure.com/{orgName}/DefaultCollection/_git/{projectName}.`

On the other hand, you choosed other event from Azure DevOps Services that you want to trigger a Jenkins build. Please choose as follows:
[image]

For more details,please check in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/jenkins?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Github trigger is defferent from azure devops git trigger, you may make mistake  triggering from github hook rather than azure repo.